# Dropdown disturbing my data

Tags: html, css

I have a problem with a dropdown menu. Whenever I click the dropdown menu, the list is disturbing my main div data like this:

My screenshot which css attribute get out me off this

[Dropdown Menu Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oRO3.jpg)

As you can see in the above image, it is pushing my data down.  Do I need to add any style to my main div or to my dropdown??

I know this is a small problem, but I'm stuck here.

Comment: did you try `position: absolute`? show us your code

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use [absolute positioning](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position) for your dropdown menu.

```
nav {
    position:absolute;
    top:100px; //how far from the top the menu is
    right:25px; //how far from the right the menu is
}
```

You can read the documentation and play with the values to get it where you like.

Answer (score 0):

Try `position:absolute` .

It may wok

Otherwise show some code